# Refresh last tab which opened new tab with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page ("/my_desk" page) that has a table and when we click on one of the table rows will open another page ("/action" page) in a new tab.
I'm looking for a way to refresh "/my_desk" page when we click on the button on "/action" page.

```html
<!-- html of "/my_desk" page -->

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/action">Finland</a></td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>Finland</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// script of "/action" page
let refreshMydesk = () => {
  // refresh "/my_desk" page
}
```

```html
<!-- html of "/action" page -->
<button onclick="refreshMydesk()">Refresh my desk</button>
```

Comment: `window.location.reload();` to refresh

Comment: my question is how to reload a specific location. does it work for other locations when I'm in other locations?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

There are two restriction related to the code from my knowledge.

- The window opened or parent must be same domain due to cors.
- Parent window where the code executed must exists on the browser.